# Selenium element not interactable button (Python, Windows, Chromedriver)

Tags: python, windows, selenium

error:     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
(Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.75)

my code: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(),"Buy Now")]').click()

html: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0wGd.png

Answer (score 0):

Since we do not have the full `HTML` page to find an accurate `xpath` and we have a small screenshot of the code, you could try to find the element using a different `xpath` technique.

```
//button[@class='button bits' and contains(., 'Buy Now')]
```

Then, you could get the element and click on it by using one of the following options. 
Option 1

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='button bits' and contains(., 'Buy Now')]").click()
```

Option 2

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='button bits' and contains(text(), 'Buy Now')]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to selenium documentation, that error occurs when:

```
"Thrown when an element is present in the DOM but interactions
with that element will hit another element do to paint order"
```

Make sure that your element is unique identified and use a wait. If is not enough, perform the click action via JavaScript.